# How to replace a column's value with another column's value in SQL Server? And how to save average of a column in another column?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have a table called `Teams` which lists teamnames, teamid and another table called `Players` that is related to `Teams` with a primary key teamnames. However I want to replace the column `teamname` in the `Players` table to teamid as it would be more performant.

1. How could I manage to do it?
2. Also each player has an overall column. I want to calculate the average overall of a team (The sum of the overall of players corresponding to this team via join/ Number of players) and save it in the team table for each team. I searched in the internet but did not find if it's possible in ssms.

Thank you so much for taking your time to help me:) I understand most of select, update, delete statements and inner joins but could not find a way to save the information in a table for each team.

Comment: Please read this to learn how to ask question.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

1. Simple! Make a new column team_id and then UPDATE using a join between teams and players.
2. You could use a "computed column" for this:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-computed-columns-in-a-table?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: I was able to complete the first part after researching "Update using joins". But for the second, do I use a computed column in "teams"? But then how do i get the overalls from "players"? Can I use values from another table in the computed column?

Comment: Oh I see, you could do this a number of ways. One way would be to initially populate the 'teams' table with the averages using a UPDATE with a join to players and then maintain the data with a Trigger (whenever someone changes the 'players' table the trigger could change the 'average' column on teams). I tend to avoid triggers because they aren't very visible but it would be a simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out how to do the second part. I had to use Group By to be able to do the average for each team separately.